# Enviar parametros con ajax a php

Tags: php, ajax, json

Tengo esta función la cual se encarga de traer datos de `php mysql` y solo muestra imágenes, luego al darle click a la imagen quiero saber cual es exactamente la que esta seleccionando, intento enviar el valor por `ajax` a `php` a `php` en donde trato de capturar `$variable=$_POST[]` pero no me guarda nada saben que estoy haciendo mal o que me esta faltando.
`servicios();`

```
function servicios() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "servicios_img.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: { peticion: "traer_servicios_activos"}
        }).done(function(res) {
            var result = JSON.parse(res);
            $.each(result, function(key, value){
                $("#container-servicios").append(
                    "<section onclick=InfoServPaq('Servicio_"+ value.id_servicio+"') id='Servicio_"+ value.id_servicio+"'>" +
                        "<a>"+ value.ser_titulo +"</a>" +
                    "</section>"
                );
                document.getElementById('Servicio_'+ value.id_servicio).style.backgroundImage = "url('img/" + value.ser_source_principal + "')";//seleccionas al id=Servicio_1 donde le aplicas el style para poner la imagen
            });
        });
}
function InfoServPaq(id) 
{       
       id = id.split("_");
        var spurl = '';
        var p = '';/* se declara la variable spurl para pasarlo por ajax*/
        switch (id[0]) 
        {
            case 'Servicio':
                spurl = 'servicios_modal.php';
                p = 'traer_info_servicio_front';
                break;
            case 'Paquete':
                spurl = 'paquetes.php';
                p = 'traer_info_paquete_front';
                break;
        }
$.ajax({
        url: spurl,
        type: "POST",
        data:{peticion:p, idsp:id[1]}/*este valor es el que no se como capturar en archivo.php  */
    }).done(function(res) {
        console.log(res); 
}
/*Archivo php */
Asi es como tengo el php y en este quiero capturar el valor de idsp:id[1] que viene en la parte de envío por ajax
     <?php
    /*include'./conexion/conexionDB.php';*/
    include('./conexion/conexionDB.php');
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){/* si existe una falla en la conexion con esta funcion manda el letrero*/
        echo "Fallo la conexon a la base de datos";
    }
    else
    {
        $consulta=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM servicios_img");
        $array_data=array();/* se declara el array*/
        if(mysqli_num_rows($consulta)>0)/*con este mysqli_num_rows se obtiene el numero de registros si es mayor a cero significa que hay registros*/
        {
            while($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)){/* con este mysqli_fetch_assoc se obtiene  un array con indices numericos y asociativos*/
                $array_data[]=$data;
            }   
        /*print_r($array_data); con print_r muestra los resultados asignados al array de php*/
        echo json_encode($array_data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);/* con json_unescaped_unicode resuelve los eslaches y simbolos*/
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: puedes explicarme un poco mas: que es lo que tienes? 1 php y 1 html?
¿De las funciones que nos muestras, como lo tienes realemente?, es decir estan dentro de un document.ready o algo asi? Gracias! ;)

Comment: Hola que tal si claro ya agregue el archivo php, y no uso el document.ready, sino desde el html tengo definido el <script src=funciones.js></script> y desde ahí mando llamarla.

Answer (score 0):

en php para cachar los datos en las peticiones de tipo post, put es asi

```
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input'); //los datos que van en data
 $data = json_decode($json); //Se convierte los datos a un objeto
 $peticion = $data->path; // accedes a la propiedad que quieres
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Oscar Plata Félix me ayudo mucho tu información ya estoy recibiendo el valor me sirvió este código por si a alguien le pasa lo mismo:$data = json_decode($json); //Se convierte los datos a un objeto. En mi archivo.php  para cachar los datos en las peticiones de tipo post con ajax lo obtuve de la siguiente manera $variable=$_POST[parametroquevienedeajax];     $data=json_decode($variable);   echo $data;